# Alert handling fails in latest IE version

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

> OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
>
> Selenium Version: 3.3.1
>
> Browser: Internet Explorer 11
>
> Browser Version: 11.953.14393.0

I was running the same test script for last 3 months. Suddenly last week it started failing in verifying the alert text. One difference I could find is now if the same alert is displayed within a short time span there is a warning with checkbox. Warning message is **don't let this page create more messages**.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertText = alert.getText();
```

`alert.getText()` should return the text.

Is there any way to disable this warning message in IE11 ? If not how can I handle this in Selenium Webdriver.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to handle alerts in Selenium.

[Link to help](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/)

To point you specific piece of code, take a look at Lines 41 to 53 in code of article.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have now is that alert is coming for very less time, which you can handle by checking whether the `alert is present or not`.

Try this code it might help.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

Let me know if it works.